# I can't echo a variable, but I can use it in a function?

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, echo

I am working on a system to transfer a table into an array over PHP and html forms. In doing so I have to echo the users ID into a hidden element on the table. Here is where I am stumped:

```
    $sqlb = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_row WHERE tid = 1');
    $numb = 0;
    while($rowsres = mysql_fetch_array($sqlb))
    {

    ....


    echo('<td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" value="'.$rowres['rid'].'" name="list[]" /></td>');

echo $rowres['rid'];

echo('<td>'.getData(1, $rowsres['rid'], 1).' '.getData(1, $rowsres['rid'], 2).'</td>');
    ....

    }
```

To explain the code a little and what is happening:

1. I start by looping through my database.
2. The first .... is me doing some simple filtering of the results
3. Then the issues start. The first echo is me trying to put a hidden value of the row ID.

The value will NOT write. I've tried print, echo, I've tried assigning it to other variables but for whatever reason it will not write.

To make things more confusing: When I use that SAME variable in the third echo statement, it works! That function getData just accesses a database and returns the first and last name of the user, which it IS doing.

I'm extremely confused and have never come across an issue like this before.

Other things:
When I dump the $rowres it returns null, same with $rowres['rid']
I've tried echoing the variable in multiple places and none will echo but again, it works with the function because the function is returning the correct first and last name to each user.

Comment: It's not valid html to have content between `<td>` elements

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($resrow)` beforehand to see everything that's in it?

Comment: Not a PHP guy, just a thought - what is the scope of the $rowres variable? It looks like it is being created in the while loop logic? Maybe it needs to be declared first, as a global variable?

Comment: the fact that `getData()` works even though `$resrow` is null just shows that `getData()` probably works with a default value which "by accident" works for you. Show us the full code as well as the result of that query when you run it directly in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two different variable names:

`$rowsres` is what your assigning things to in the loop and what your passing into `getData`.

`$rowres` (note only one 's') is what you're trying to echo.  This is a completely separate variable which has nothing assigned to it.

Comment: I was just looking at my code and you are right. I can't believe that I overlooked that. It's been hours. I appreciate your help and apologize for the stupid question. Thank you again.